# YouTube video in ListView

Tags: android, android-listview, youtube-api, android-adapter

I am creating a ListView that contains utube clips(user can view the utube video WITHIN the list). What view is best to use in this case? YouTubePlayerView? VideoView? I prefer not to use a WebView because of memory issues....Thanks!

Edit: Is there any way I can initiate YouTubePlayerView in my adapter in the getView function?

Comment: Go with video view as web view in every list item will hamper the Scrolling

Comment: Do you have any experience in this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's a good idea to use `YouTubePlayerView` or `VideoView` in each item of the ListView:

- I'm not sure if it's possible at all for `YouTubePlayerView` - I haven't tried doing so, nor I've seen an example,
- even if it's possible, it won't be effective, especially when scrolling - you'll need to update every `YouTubePlayerView`/`VideoView` item providing new Uri, which will lead to lags and ineffective traffic usage.

I'd suggest using [Bitmap cache](https://github.com/chrisbanes/Android-BitmapCache) for displaying video thumbnails in `ImageView` for each item. To play video within the item I'd replace (or hide) the `ImageView` with the `YouTubePlayerView` when user selects this item from the list. When user selects another item you'll need to remove the `YouTubePlayerView` from previously selected item, get the thumbnail back and so on.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! However, how will Bitmap cache this solve the issue of viewing the clip WITHIN the list?

Comment: This will let you avoid adding `YouTubePlayerView` into every item of the ListView and will manage your bitmaps efficiently out of box.